# Success Channel in Spring integration to be dynamic

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm sending a new payload header to a success channel using an advice and in the success channel I'm sending the file_originalFile to FTP server using `outboundAdapter`, the issue is that success channel is only accepting static `outboundAdapter` and it is working fine,it receives the payload and send it to FTP server, I want to have the success channel outboundAdapter accepts different FTP connections at runtime, so if I add connection to FTP server 1 and the payload hits the success channel it sends it to FTP server 1 and then I add FTP server 2 then the new payload will be sent to FTP server 2 from the success channel, I tried to remove `@Bean` on the success and pass the FTP session factory in the parameter at run time same as what I'm doing with the first flow in the code but it is recognizing it as success channel for the advice and if I add the `@Bean` with the parameter of the Branch the application will not run.

Here is the code I have in place where I have the success channel taking `createNewFtpSessionFactory()` as predefined connection, I want to have it take `createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch)` where the branch is FTP server that I will be adding at run time and continue to be a success channel for the advice.

```
/*
* Creating the outbound adaptor to send files from local to FTP server
*
* */


public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch) {

    return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(dataSource), "foo"))),//FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))
            .enrichHeaders(h ->h.headerExpression("file_originalFile", "new java.io.File('BEY/FEFOexport" + myBranch.getBranchCode() + ".csv')",true))
            .transform(p -> {
                LOG1.info("Sending file " + p + " to FTP branch " + myBranch.getBranchCode());

                return p;
            })

            .log()
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(false)
                    .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()), e -> e.advice(expressionAdvice()))

            .get();
}

/*
* Creating the advice for routing the payload of the outbound message on different expressions (success, failure)
*
* */

@Bean
public Advice expressionAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("success.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload.delete() + ' was successful'");
    //advice.setFailureChannelName("failure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' was bad, with reason: ' + #exception.cause.message");
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    return advice;
}

/*
* Creating FTP connection based on the branch ftp data entered.
* */

public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory(Branch branch) {
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(branch.getHost());
    factory.setUsername(branch.getUsern());
    factory.setPort(branch.getFtpPort());
    factory.setPassword(branch.getPassword());
    return factory;
}

public DefaultFtpSessionFactory createNewFtpSessionFactory() {
    final DefaultFtpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost("xxxx");
    factory.setUsername("xx");
    factory.setPort(xx);
    factory.setPassword("xxxx");
    return factory;
}

/*
* Creating a metadata store to be used across the application flows to prevent reprocessing the file if it is already processed.
* This will save the new file in a metadata table in the DB with the state of the report, so when a new copy comes with different date it will be processed only.
* */
@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);
}

/*
* Success channel that will handle the AdviceMessage from the outbound adapter
*
* */

   @Bean
public IntegrationFlow success(){
    return f -> f.transform("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']")
             //    .handle(Message.class,(m,h)-> this.delegatingSessionFactory().setThreadKey(m, h.get(String.valueOf("inputMessage.headers['file_originalFile']",1,3)))
            .handle(Message.class,(m,h)-> delegatingSessionFactory().setThreadKey(m,"CAI"))
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectory("/ftp/erbranch/EDMS/FEFO/History/").get());
}

@Bean
public DelegatingSessionFactory delegatingSessionFactory(){

    SessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile> sff = sessionFactoryLocator();
    return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(sff);

}

@Bean
public SessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile> sessionFactoryLocator() {

    final List<Branch> branchConnections = new ArrayList<>();
    branchRepository.findAll().forEach(branchConnections::add);
    final Map<Object, SessionFactory<FTPFile>> factories = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    /*if(branchConnections.isEmpty()){
        //return null;
        factories.put("BEY",createNewFtpSessionFactory());
    }*/

    for (Branch br : branchConnections) {
        // create a factory for every key containing server type, url and port
        if (factories.get(br.getId()) == null) {
            factories.put(br.getBranchCode(), createNewFtpSessionFactory(br));
        }
    }
      return new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<FTPFile>(factories,createNewFtpSessionFactory());//,defaultFtpSessionFactory);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that; the bean definition is only read once, during startup.

Use a `DelegatingSessionFactory` with custom `SessionFactoryLocator` and add some logic the `onSuccess` flow to create the new factory if it doesn't already exist and set up the thread to invoke the factory based on the `Branch` (call `setThreadKey()`).

Comment: Is it something close to what I can see in this link?https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/session/DelegatingSessionFactoryTests.java 
I could not find the proper was as per your suggested solution although I know it is the right one @Gary Russell

Comment: Yes; you just need to set the key before calling the adapter.

Comment: I edited my code as I understood, but still having errors in 'success()' and not sure what to be done, errors are in this part'.handle(delegatingSessionFactory().setThreadKey(""))
            .Ftp.outboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)' ... can you please guide me if I'm doing what should be done correctly or I'm missing the concept here? In the 'sessionFactoryLocator()' im creating connections to all the branches that I have inserted in the DB at run time an adding them to the 'delegatingSessionFactory', then using it in the success channel...thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: You need to add the delegate factories to the `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator` used by the `DelegatingSessionFactory`; each factory has a `key` which you must use in `setThreadKey()` to select the desired factory.

Comment: In method `sessionFactory()` I'm iterating in a list of branches that I added and then adding them to a Map `factiories` with branch code as key, and finally adding factories to `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator` so now in the success channel where I need to use the `setThreadkey()`? if I'm using `Ftp.outboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory().setThreadKey("BEY"), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)` it is telling me that I cannot use void, should I do something like if branch is BEY then setThreadKey() and then in the adaptor I call getSession("BEY") or something else?thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: One more time; `Ftp.outboundAdapter()` is processed one-time only, to set up the infrastructure, it has nothing to do with runtime. You just need the factory there; then, in your flow add a component `.handle(...)` that sets the threadKey based on the message information.

Comment: I had the chance to work on it again, I updated my code for the **success**, **delegatingSessionFactory** and **sessionFactoryLocator** methods, if I run the app now and for example I entered branch CAI that should have key as CAI and should send to CAI on success, but it is sending to the default session that is BEY and not picking the correct session factory, trying it now with static threadKey to make sure it is working but not and if I add another branch it sends also to the default one, is there anything I missed adding here in the flow?thanks @Gary Russell

Comment: Haven't heard back on this, shall I submit a new question?thanks@Gary Russell

Comment: I was out last week and missed this; but, yes, a new question with your current configuration would help. They don't like extended commentary here.